# Ubuntu 12.04 Wifi Hotspot can't provide internet for 2 devices simultaneously

Tags: wireless, connection-sharing

The problem is in the title.. I'm using an old laptop to distribute the internet connection.

The hotspot was created easily, and i can connect one device at a time, and use the internet provided by the old laptop. If i connect 2 devices, both of them loose internet connection, and the wifi keeps disconnecting. 
Is it a hardware problem? (weaker(?) wifi card, although i tested with 2 of them, or over all poor performance of the laptop (is a toshiba qosmio f20-132)). Or some kind of bad configuration?

This is something to use sporadically, i don't intend to buy an access point, so any comment regarding this is kinda of useless, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be your wifi card is limited to provide a single channel of communication, so that you will be able to connect to just one device at one time.

You can get USB based wifi cards that support full fledged access point support for around $10 from ebay or amazon

Answer (score 0):

My guess is weak hardware. This one is certainly your case, you are booting from an USB disk and using very fast speed which causes system resources to collapse, and has to shutdown one, and because the USB disk is the boot disk it chooses to disconnect the Wi-Fi! Solution is to connect the USB disk to an hub of less speed, like if was connected to USB3, use an USB2 hub which causes the USB disk to work at USB2 speed, if it was using USB2 then use an USB1.1 hub...